# JavaFX 8 iterate hash map

Tags: hashmap, javafx-8

Given this hashmap:

```
HashMap<TitledPane, Boolean> paneMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I'm trying to set all values in the map to false (values are set selectively in the application after 'clearing' the map), but no matter what I have tried I cannot get an appropriate iterator which will allow me to set each boolean value. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Just spoke to someone by phone and there is a very simple answer which I just didn't see in the end, because I tried to make it too complicated (I hadn't realised that 'put' replaces any existing values.

```
 for (TitledPane p : paneMap.keySet()){
        paneMap.put(p, Boolean.FALSE);
    }
```

Comment: A similar Java 8 solution would be `paneMap.keySet().stream().forEach(p -> paneMap.put(p, false));`

Comment: @ItachiUchiha you don't need a stream(). just         `paneMap.keySet().forEach(key -> paneMap.put(key, false) );`

Comment: or change the value of each entry: `paneMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> entry.setValue(false))`

Comment: @Win.ubuntu My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda:

```
paneMap.replaceAll((k, v) -> Boolean.FALSE);
```